# Spark Standalone Application hangs at the last point

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop2, apache-spark-sql

I am relatively new to Spark and wrote a simple script using python and spark SQL. My problem is that it is perfectly allright at the starting phase of the execution but gradually it slowed down and at the end of the last phase the whole application hangs. Here is the code snippet where the application get hanged-

```
hivectx.registerDataFrameAsTable(aggregatedDataV1,"aggregatedDataV1")
q1 = "SELECT *, (Total_Sale/Sale_Weeks) as Average_Sale_Per_SaleWeek, (Total_Weeks/Sale_Weeks) as Velocity FROM aggregatedDataV1"
aggregatedData = hivectx.sql(q1)
aggregatedData.show(100)
```

I have got the following on the terminal -

```
16/03/29 09:05:50 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 96.0 in stage 416.0 (TID 19992) in 41924 ms on 10.9.0.7 (104/200)
16/03/29 09:05:50 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 108.0 in stage 416.0 (TID 20004) in 24608 ms on 10.9.0.10 (105/200)
16/03/29 09:05:50 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 105.0 in stage 416.0 (TID 20001) in 24610 ms on 10.9.0.10 (106/200)
16/03/29 09:05:55 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 116.0 in stage 416.0 (TID 20012, 10.9.0.10, partition 116,NODE_LOCAL, 2240 bytes)
16/03/29 09:06:31 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 99.0 in stage 416.0 (TID 19995) in 78435 ms on 10.9.0.7 (110/200)
16/03/29 09:06:40 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 119.0 in stage 416.0 (TID 20015, 10.9.0.10, partition 119,NODE_LOCAL, 2240 bytes)
16/03/29 09:07:12 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 122.0 in stage 416.0 (TID 20018, 10.9.0.7, partition 122,NODE_LOCAL, 2240 bytes) 
16/03/29 09:07:16 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 123.0 in stage 416.0 (TID 20019, 10.9.0.7, partition 123,NODE_LOCAL, 2240 bytes)
16/03/29 09:07:28 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 111.0 in stage 416.0 (TID 20007) in 110198 ms on 10.9.0.7 (114/200)
16/03/29 09:07:52 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 124.0 in stage 416.0 (TID 20020, 10.9.0.10, partition 124,NODE_LOCAL, 2240 bytes)
16/03/29 09:08:08 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 110.0 in stage 416.0 (TID 20006) in 150023 ms on 10.9.0.7 (115/200)
16/03/29 09:08:12 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 113.0 in stage 416.0 (TID 20009) in 154120 ms on 10.9.0.7 (116/200)
16/03/29 09:08:16 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 116.0 in stage 416.0 (TID 20012) in 145691 ms on 10.9.0.10 (117/200)
```

After that the whole application is hanged. I have my spark-env.sh file with the following configuration :

```
export SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS="azuremaster.westus.cloudapp.azure.com"
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES=1
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES=2
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=3G
export SPARK_MASTER_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.defaultCores=1"
export SPARK_WORKER_PORT="8888"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3
export SPARK_HIVE=true
```

I am using **3 Node Clusters**. One ***Master*** with **2 Cores and 4 GB Memory** and other two ***Workers*** with **4 Cores and 7 GB Memory**.

I have tried the following so far -

- Increasing no of executor cores
- Increasing/Decreasing executors with different amounts of resources.

I have --

1. Spark -1.6.0
2. Java 7
3. scala 2.10.4
4. Prebuilt hadoop 2.3
5. Prebuilt Hive

After running the application for 2 hours it is giving the errors.

[The terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58hQo.png)

I'm guessing a configuration needs to be tuned but have no idea which one. I will be grateful if anyone have knowledge whats is going on and suggest some helping information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post image of your DAG visualization for this stage from spark UI.

Comment: @Abhishek Anand I have edited the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your out of memory error suggests you may need to bump up the driver-memory. By default this is 2GB. I have run into similar issues and passing custom configurations via a spark-submit flag works.

Try this:

`spark-submit --driver-memory = 4g app.py`

If this doesn't work; you'll need to look in the spark web UI or ganglia to see how much memory is being used during execution. Ganglia will allow you to see how much memory is being used and if you need more memory for the job.